# Variance and covariance between 2 variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, covariance, variance

[image]

[image]

For this problem, we can simply use this formula to find the upper bound for $Cov(X,Y)$, given the relation between $Var(X+Y)$ and $Var(X), Var(Y)$. Why do we need extra details?

Comment: We need to derive an upper bound for the covariance. This is an equality, and the covariance cannot be found since we can't find the variance of $X+Y$, but instead have a bound for it.

Comment: $$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\leqslant\frac12\left(\frac12-1\right)\left(25-3^2+4-0^2\right)=-5$$

Comment: Oops, I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, which formula did you use?